# Help with translation of 今後ともよろしくお願い致します

Tags: meaning, greetings

> こちらこそありがとうございます！
>   今後ともよろしくお願い致します‍♂️

First sentence is fine.
Second is tricky, I don't know exactly meaning.
But my guess is, From now on we can be friends. is it correct and what is this male symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

今後ともよろしくお願い致します is a set expression which can be used in various situations and can convey different nuances in meaning, depending on the context.

See some examples of sentences in: [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E4%BB%8A%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%82%88%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%8A%E9%A1%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99).

About the よろしくお願いします／よろしくお願い致します part, the topic has already been brought up on this Japanese Language site:

- [How to say よろしくお願いします in English?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/37182/how-to-say-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%8A%E9%A1%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-in-english)
- [What does よろしくおねがいします mean when departing?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/87/what-does-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%8A%E3%81%AD%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-mean-when-departing)
- [When to use “どうぞよろしくお願い致します。” in a greeting?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18264/when-to-use-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9E%E3%82%88%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%8A%E9%A1%98%E3%81%AD%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E8%87%B4%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-in-a-greeting)

And since it is somehow a wish or a sincere request, and highly cultural, it is usually said while bowing more or less deeply at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me answer here only about the last two characters at the end of the sentence.

Under my computer system too (OS X El Capitan), they appear separate, but on very recent operating systems, they are supposed to be combined into one single [Man Bowing Deeply](https://emojipedia.org/man-bowing-deeply/) *emoji* (絵文字) character. This is a new feature introduced in Unicode...

For the technically-oriented people, here is a screenshot showing how the emoji is decomposed... As I already mentioned, it should appear as one character in the upper field on more recent systems...

[image]

Comment: Thanks very good info. But I still doesn't understand meaning of second sentence.